# How to update array element in mongodb document?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

This query is updating successfully:

```
db.product.updateMany({"Rno":{$in:["111","222","333"]}},{$set:{"subjwmarks.maths":99}});
```

Before updating:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a572886964d881dab9f1f55"),
    "Rno" : "111",
    "stuname" : "sravan",
    "subjwmarks" : [ 
        {
            "maths" : 88.0,
            "english" : 99.0,
            "Clang" : 97.0
        }
    ],
    "total" : 284.0,
    "grade" : "A",
    "organization" : "Tata"
};
```

After updating the query returns this value:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a572886964d881dab9f1f55"),
    "Rno" : "111",
    "stuname" : "sravan",
    "subjwmarks" : [ 
        {
            "maths" : 99,
        }
    ],
    "total" : 284.0,
    "grade" : "A",
    "organization" : "Tata"
};
```

Value should be:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a572886964d881dab9f1f55"),
    "Rno" : "111",
    "stuname" : "sravan",
    "subjwmarks" : [ 
        {
            "maths" : 99,
            "english" : 99.0,
            "Clang" : 97.0
        }
    ],
    "total" : 284.0,
    "grade" : "A",
    "organization" : "Tata"
}
```

But other elements of that array were deleted.

Can anyone suggest how to fix this problem?

Comment: Hello, can you please provide a sample of what was in database before and after the command; and what you wanted to have after the command, so that we can understand what you are trying to do ?

Comment: before updating:

Comment: {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a572886964d881dab9f1f55"),
    "Rno" : "111",
    "stuname" : "sravan",
    "subjwmarks" : [ 
        {
            "maths" : 88.0,
            "english" : 99.0,
            "Clang" : 97.0
        }
    ],
    "total" : 284.0,
    "grade" : "A",
    "organization" : "Tata"
}:

Comment: after updating:

Comment: {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a572886964d881dab9f1f55"),
    "Rno" : "111",
    "stuname" : "sravan",
    "subjwmarks" : [ 
        {
            "maths" : 99,
             }
    ],
    "total" : 284.0,
    "grade" : "A",
    "organization" : "Tata"
}

Comment: (please add into your question; use edit link)
Also to markup your post, please add 4 spaces before each line of code (so it will render prettier on StackOverflow)

Answer (score 0):

```
db.product.updateMany({"Rno":{$in:["111","222","333"]}, subjwmarks:{ $exists: true}},{$set:{"subjwmarks.$.maths":100}});
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

```
Note: subjwmarks must be in query part
```